# How to format Date in SQL Result?

Tags: sql

```
Select supplierno as Supplier, duedate as date
from table
union
Select supplierno as Supplier, duedate as date
from table
Union
-----New union
order by 2
```

The result looks like this:

```
Supplier    date
5000        2014-10-05 00-00-00-000
5010        2014-05-05 00-00-00-000
```

I must use the datetime to get the sorting right. 
How can I format the date better in the result?

I want this:

```
Supplier    date
5000        05.10.2014
5010        05.05.2014
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Date formatting is notoriously database-specific.  (You should tag your question with the right database.)

Comment: The answer depends on the sql dialect you are using. Every sql dialect has several functions converting times. Can't you get them from a manual?

Comment: Your question is not about sorting or about unions, it's about formatting. Please change the tittle. Also tell us the name of the RDBMS.

Comment: fwiw, this work is best done in the client application anyway.

Answer (score 0):

IF all tables dates are in datetime format, then the below should work:

```
;with CTE
AS
(
Select supplierno as Supplier, duedate as date
from table
union
Select supplierno as Supplier, duedate as date
from table
Union
-----New union
order by 2
)
select
Supplier, convert(varchar(100), [date], 104)
from cte
```

Comment: I would not name my column as "date".  Rather use something less likely to be reserved somewhere.